# Piped un-tar kill pipe when finished extracting given file from tarball

Tags: linux, bash, curl, pipe, tar

There is a big tarball that I am downloading using curl. I am just interested in one file within that tarball. So currently I am piping the output of curl to tar.

```
$ curl -S http://url/of/big/tarball.tar.gz | tar -xv path/of/one/file
```

Although it works fine this way. It will still download the humongous tarball completely even when the required file is already un-tared. Is there a way to interrupt it automatically when tar has finished extracting the required file?

#### Edit: For anyone wandering web for the same question. I ended up creating a small bash script

```
trap 'kill $(jobs -p)' EXIT
curl -S "${URL}" | tar -C "${OUTPUT_DIR}" -xv "${FILES[@]}" 2>&1 | head -"${FILES_CNT}" > "${CTRL_FILE}" 2>&1 &
 # Wait for the required files to be found in the tar
until [[ -s "${CTRL_FILE}" && $(wc -l "${CTRL_FILE}" | cut -d' ' -f 8) -ge "${FILES_CNT}" ]]; do
    sleep 10s
done
```

Comment: Try `tar -zxv --occurrence=1 path/of/one/file < <(curl -S http://url/of/big/tarball.tar.gz)`

Comment: occurrence=1 is not supported in my current mac :(

Comment: Post your script as an answer, please.

Comment: Note that in theory, the same file can appear more than once in a single tar file.  Not a common occurrence, but there are options that make that feasible.  You have to decide what you want to do about that.  Ignore the possibility is probably a valid decision.

Comment: When using --occurrence, gzip has a bug where if the app that launched tar had SIGPIPE set as ignored (python does this by default), gzip leaves it ignored and later it gets -EPIPE when writing uncompressed data, and exits with an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
trap 'kill $(jobs -p)' EXIT
curl -S "${URL}" | tar -C "${OUTPUT_DIR}" -xv "${FILES[@]}" 2>&1 | head -"${FILES_CNT}" > "${CTRL_FILE}" 2>&1 &
# Wait for the required files to be found in the tar
until [[ -s "${CTRL_FILE}" && $(wc -l "${CTRL_FILE}" | cut -d' ' -f 8) -ge "${FILES_CNT}" ]]; do
    sleep 10s
done
```